# Magazine-like horizontal scrolling in HTML5 & CSS3

Tags: html, css

I'd like to use HTML5 and CSS3 to make a magazine like [asidemag.com](http://asidemag.com/) but how can I enable the horizontal scrolling like that?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to begin considering how people define the sideways swiping, an important first step in how these things get put together. Horizontal scrolling is not really something that is 'enabled', but an integral part of the magazine that is 'built'. You can contact them to find out how they did it, should you like.

Your steps are to read the touch events of the user, understand how they are working (direction) and then how the visible items on the web page are handled to integrate the swiping behaviour. This will depend on your proficiency with javascript, css and html5, and willingness to build the system itself.

I have been working on an engine for this, but the asidemag.com concept handles the data differently from mine. They use ajax to load each page as needed, which allows for a larger magazine, and mine just loaded an entire web page and 'built' it to read like a magazine. Theirs only works on the iPad, and mine works on most devices, including ie7.

How much effort do you want to invest in building a magazine? You can contact asidemag to find out how to do it on their system if you want it easier, or you can poke around on the net to find out how to do it yourself if you have more time to devote to it.

Comment: If it's possible I'd love to take a look to the project you did :)

Comment: This is an older version of it (the latest is undergoing 'tweaks')

http://stacks.acadnet.ca/reblend1

the code may be a bit clunky... but it gives you an idea of what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Check out treesaverjs.com it's a framework for creating magazine style web sites.